# Server reachable from browser and unreachable from android app on same phone

Tags: android, port, firewall

I am making a connection to some server and sending some https request to it. It is running on port 443. I am inside some network which is protected by firewall. Now when i hit that server with my android phone's chrome browser,it gives the expected response "https://someip". Now when i send a https request to that same server using my android app. It gives a timeout error. I believe my request is not able to reach the server and is blocked by firewall. If i host the server inside my network,i get the expected response from my app. So when the server is hosted outside,why am i able to get response through my phone's chrome browser and not through my app? PS: I am also able to get response from the server when hosted on outside network if i use cellular data instead on wifi network

Comment: Do you have a proxy configured in chrome? Anyhow, this is something we cannot solve here. Talk to your network admin.

Comment: @Henry yes i do have a proxy configured  configured for that  particular wifi connection....it's a manual proxy that is configured while selecting any wifi connection

Comment: So most likely your network blocks all direct access to external ports 80 and 443. A connection must go via the proxy.